# python print command causes I/O error

Tags: python, printing, io, enthought, canopy

I have a python code that has been running fine on several computers for several years. I recently installed python (same version) and uploaded the same code on a new computer. The code will run fine for several days until all of a sudden it experiences an error when trying to do a simple print command. The print command is to print to the main console, not to a file, like a 'print i got this far' type of QC check. I can comment out all the print commands but I need those QC checks.

```
C:\X\halo1_rt_v6.5.py in halo_storeFile(halo1Config, product, spreftype,        dateTime, ending, height)
    164         fnout_recent =  halo1Config["LATEST"]+halo1Config["NAME"]+ "_"  +  product.upper()+"_"+dateTime+"-"+spreftype + ending
    165         fdest = dst + fnout_time
--> 166         print 'STORING: ',fdest, fnout_latest, fnout_recent
    167     else:
    168         fnout_time   =  halo1Config["NAME"] +"_" + product.upper()+ "-" + spreftype+"_"+dateTime+"_" +str(height) + '_m'+ ending


C:\Users\Default.Default-PC\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.7.4.3348.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\iostream.pyc in write(self, string)
    315 
    316             is_child = (not self._is_master_process())
--> 317             self._buffer.write(string)
    318             if is_child:
    319                 # newlines imply flush in subprocesses

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Is it something wrong with my python version, Enthought Canopy, or ipykernel? I tried updating ipykernel. All the code does is print simple statements to the console so I have no idea why this would encounter I/O errors - I'm not writing to any file and the code works fine 90% of the time!

Thanks for the help

Comment: I assume you're not running this script through Canopy itself? I'm not sure I can see how that would be an issue.

Comment: Whatever the issue is, I think it would be better to create a small script that runs in the same way and test from that, rather than waiting ages for the issue to arise. I can't test anything here from what you posted but the path in the final part of the traceback... I've not seen anything like that.

Comment: A random guess that might not lead anywhere, are you running a virtual environment?

Comment: Yes, Canopy 1.7.4 Python always uses virtual environments. (Canopy 2.x uses flat environments).

Comment: I am running this script through Canopy itself (launching Enthought Canopy, running the script). Could it be a work path issue? 
I will try to run using a smaller script in the mean-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running the code in the Canopy GUI's IPython Panel? This is a Jupyter / IPython Qtconsole, which has a 2-process (kernel:frontend) architecture, more fragile than a 1-process architecture (e.g. it needs to communicate your print statements over your localhost.

So if this is a long-running program, it would be more robust to run it in a simple ipython terminal (opened from a Canopy Command Prompt with `ipython`).

Comment: I could try running it in a separate terminal without Canopy; it's just strange that I haven't experienced this problem related to Canopy until now. I will let you know what comes of running it separately in cmd or something as you suggest.